# swift tableview separator line missing between first and second row

Tags: swift, tableview, cell

I created a table and it seems the separator line between the first and second cell is missing and the rest are there. If I scroll to the top and back the line appears :
[image]

Below is the tableview rows functions. I read from a mysql database and display the rows.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return dbarray_id.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    //for(var i = 0; i < dbarray_id.count; i += 1)
    //for i in 0..<dbarray_code.count
    //{
    //    //newVars.put_timelog("cellForRowAtIndexPath_uiswitch :\(uiswitch_onoff[i])  \(uiswitch_enabled[i])")
    //}

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "pushgroups_tvc") as! pushgroups_tvc

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    cell.txtsubject.text = dbarray_title[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    cell.txtbody.text = dbarray_description[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] 

    cell.txtsubject.numberOfLines=0
    cell.txtsubject.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping

    cell.txtbody.numberOfLines=0
    cell.txtbody.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping

    cell.txtsubject.textColor = UIColor.blue
    cell.txtsubject.font = newVars.font_subject
    cell.txtbody.font = newVars.font_body

    cell.addgroup.tag = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row
    //update switch to selected value
    //cell.addgroup.on = false
    cell.addgroup.isOn = uiswitch_onoff[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    if uiswitch_enabled[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] == true
    {
        cell.addgroup.isEnabled = true
        cell.addgroup.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
    else
    {
        cell.addgroup.isEnabled = false
        cell.addgroup.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    cell.txtaccesscode.text = ""
    cell.txtaccesscode.isEnabled = true

    cell.txtaccesscode.tag = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row
    cell.txtaccesscode.tintColor = UIColor.blue
    cell.txtaccesscode.autocapitalizationType = .allCharacters


    //GGGGGG
    cell.txtaccesscode.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldTyping_access), for: .editingChanged)

    if dbarray_public[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] == "Y"
    {
         //cell.backgroundColor =  UIColor.blueColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2)
         cell.txtaccesscode.text = ""
         cell.txtaccesscode.isEnabled = false
         cell.addgroup.isEnabled = true
         cell.txtaccesscode.isHidden = true
    }
    if dbarray_public[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] == "R"
    {
        cell.txtaccesscode.isHidden = false
        //cell.backgroundColor =  UIColor.redColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2)
    }
    if dbarray_public[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] == "H"
    {
        //cell.backgroundColor =  UIColor.greenColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2)
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero

     cell.backgroundColor = newVars.hexStringToUIColor(hex: newVars.tableview1_background_color).withAlphaComponent(CGFloat(newVars.tableview1_background_color_alpha))

    return cell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    newVars.put_timelog(timedata: "GORDON pushgroups_vc_textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField ")

    //tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.singleLineEtched
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.singleLine
    tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.black
    //tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red //overrides cell color
    tableView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
}
```

Comment: is the screenshot from simulator or a real device?

Comment: Check on Real Device , On Simulator it seems like but on device it wil work

Comment: I checked Both simulator and iPad and the same, no line between first and second

Comment: Can you provide some sample code? Maybe your cell is overlapping the separator or something like that

Comment: Try running the simulator at 100% zoom.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that setting:

```
cell.selectionStyle = .none
```

And then programmatically selecting a cell, like in the viewDidLoad method will cause this bug.
I had the same problem and solved it using accessory checkmark and disabling selection. After I removed the code that selected the first cell by default, the bug disappeared.